# Get current location using workers

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I have an application similar to Cabify (drivers) and I try to get the current location of the driver, I had done this with IntentService, but now I want to use workers, but I don't know why when I try to get the location, this is null, any ideas ?

My doWork function is something like this

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    if (applicationContext.needPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        Report.exception("No GPS permission")
        return Result.failure()
    }

    val fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    val loc = fusedLocationClient.lastLocation?.await() ?: return Result.retry()

    onLocationWork(loc)

    return Result.success()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that your last location is unknown and you need to cover such cases. Like

```
val lastKnownLocation = fusedClient.lastKnownLocation ?: requestCurrentLocation()
```

In your `requestCurrentLocation()`

```
val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY) // your accuracy here
    .setInterval(5000L) // 5 sec, your interval here
    .setFastestInterval(5000L) // 5 sec, your interval here
fusedClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper())
```

If you need to get the location only once and it's not about listening to it all the time, you should wrap this code with a `suspendCancellableCoroutine` or a `callbackFlow` and subscribe to updates, when you get a location - remove all updates and the location callback.

Comment: Yes I think you are right, because I tested my app on a real device and I can get the location, I think it's an Android Studio emulator issue or something.